# System lag after Ubuntu update - how to troubleshoot & revert back?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 18.10

I just updated my Lenovo X1 Yoga 3rd gen running on Ubuntu 18.10. The machine has been running great, that is until today after the update. It is extremely slow.

I am wondering how to troubleshoot and also as an alternative is there a way to undo the update?

Comment: What do you mean by "extremely slow"?

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer to see if that solves the slowness?

Comment: I rebooted, twice. And it was still doing it. But now after restarting it again a few times it's back to normal. So, I am not sure what it was, but it is not doing anymore...

As far as what I meant by slow, I mean like laggy. Lack of response or slow response, as if you were playing your favorite multiplayer game online with a high ping =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't assume that an upgrade is responsible**. Maybe it is, maybe it's not. Maybe you picked up a crypto-miner or other malware instead. 'Maybe' lots of possibilities.

Here's one first-pass approach to rule out many of those possibilities:

1. Look at `top` to see what the big resource-consuming processes are.
2. Look at `free` to see if you are swapping.
3. Look at `df -h` and `df -i` to see if your storage is full.
4. Check /var/log/apt/history.log to see what was recently upgraded. Look for frequently-used applications and new kernels.
5. If the logfile shows that a new kernel was installed, try rebooting into the previous (older) kernel to see if performance suddenly resumes.
6. Review /var/log/syslog for unusual activity, warnings, and errors.

If NONE of these provides any clue, then it's time to rule out hardware: MEMTEST, SMART Test, and the like.

My 18.10 is as fast as ever, so it's not a universal problem.